# Is it possible to observe friends location from foursquare/swarm on desktop computer?

Tags: social-networking

Foursquare/swarm is geolocating social network. I can see on my mobile when my friends are (if they report their location).

Is it possible to observe locations from desktop computer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mobile app and its associated web page.

Answer (score 1):

Click on 'Friend Activity'.
You still could see the locations, eventhough 4sq has moved over to swarmapp.
[image]

Like this:

[image]